# Subclass Python str class and do a string comparison with pure string

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm subclassing string class (`BioSequence`), and subclassing that as well (`Exon`). These classes are expected to have equality comparison with string data and other data, and if comparison to a pure string class, they should be a the combined result of string comparison and comparisons of other data.

**EDIT:** I meant when comparing to a pure string class, it should just be a simple string comparison. Sorry.

Code is as follows:

```
class BioSequence(str):
    def __new__(cls, content, pos_s = 0, pos_e = -1):
        return str.__new__(cls, content)

    def __init__(self, content, pos_s = 0, pos_e = -1):
        if pos_e == -1:
            pos_e = pos_s + len(self)
        self.pos_s_chrom = pos_s
        self.pos_e_chrom = pos_e

    def __eq__(self, otherSequence):
        ''' Two sequnces are equal if pos_s_chrom, pos_e_chrom, and sequence itself is the same
           or if otherSequence is just a string, do a normal string comparison
        '''
        if isinstance(otherSequence, self.__class__):
            return super.__eq__(self, otherSequence) and self.pos_s_chrom == otherSequence.pos_s_chrom and \
                self.pos_e_chrom == otherSequence.pos_e_chrom
        else: # just a string comparison
            #print('self:', self, type(str(self)))
            #print('otherSequence:', otherSequence, type(otherSequence))
            return str.__eq__(self, otherSequence)

    def __ne__(self, otherSequence):
        return not self.__eq__(otherSequence)

    def __str__(self):
        className = type(self).__name__
        #return '[%s %s (s: %s, e: %s)]' % (className, self[:], self.pos_s_chrom, self.pos_e_chrom)
        return '[%s %s (s: %s, e: %s)]' % (className, super().__getitem__(slice(None, None, None)), self.pos_s_chrom, self.pos_e_chrom)

class Exon(BioSequence):
    pass

print(BioSequence('abcde', 10) == BioSequence('abcde', 10)) # True
print(Exon('abcde', 10) == Exon('abcde', 10)) # True
print(BioSequence('abcde', 10) == 'abcde') # True
print(Exon('abcde', 10) == 'abcde') # True
print(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10) == 'abcde') # Want True, but False here
```

I want the result of the last line above to be `True`; however I can't get it to work.

Somehow `print(str.__eq__(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10), 'abcde'))` yields `False`. How come?

Comment: Having a `str` subclass implement `__str__` is a recipe for confusion.

Comment: Interesting! I have a theory that the culprit is `str.__eq__(self, otherSequence)`. I'm on my phone right now, but I'll run some tests shortly. In the meantime,  put a `print` into your `__str__` method so you can see when it's called, and then do your `__eq__` tests.

Comment: @user2357112 Agreed. But subclassing the built-in types is never a task for the easily confused, or the faint of heart. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user2357112 and Serge Ballesta have explained the cause of your problem. Here's an updated version of your code that defines `__repr__` instead of `__str__`, with a couple of debugging print calls thrown in and a few other minor adjustments). However, I agree with Serge's suggestion: don't subclass `str`, instead make a class that stores the `content` string as a member. You could have that class's `__str__` return your `content` string. It won't be quite as convenient, but it will be less headache-inducing than your current approach.

```
class BioSequence(str):
    def __new__(cls, content, pos_s = 0, pos_e = -1):
        return str.__new__(cls, content)

    def __init__(self, content, pos_s = 0, pos_e = -1):
        if pos_e == -1:
            pos_e = pos_s + len(self)
        self.pos_s_chrom = pos_s
        self.pos_e_chrom = pos_e

    def __eq__(self, otherSequence):
        ''' Two sequnces are equal if pos_s_chrom, pos_e_chrom, and sequence itself is the same
           or if otherSequence is just a string, do a normal string comparison
        '''
        if isinstance(otherSequence, self.__class__):
            print('SAME', self.__class__, otherSequence)
            return (super().__eq__(otherSequence) 
                and self.pos_s_chrom == otherSequence.pos_s_chrom 
                and self.pos_e_chrom == otherSequence.pos_e_chrom)
        else: # just a string comparison
            print('OTHER', self.__class__, otherSequence)
            return super().__eq__(otherSequence)

    def __ne__(self, otherSequence):
        return not self.__eq__(otherSequence)

    def __repr__(self):
        className = self.__class__.__name__
        print('CLASS', className)
        #return '[%s %s (s: %s, e: %s)]' % (className, self[:], self.pos_s_chrom, self.pos_e_chrom)
        return '[%s %s (s: %s, e: %s)]' % (className, super().__getitem__(slice(None, None, None)), self.pos_s_chrom, self.pos_e_chrom)

class Exon(BioSequence):
    pass

print(BioSequence('abcde', 10) == BioSequence('abcde', 10)) # True
print(Exon('abcde', 10) == Exon('abcde', 10)) # True
print(BioSequence('abcde', 10) == 'abcde') # True
print(Exon('abcde', 10) == 'abcde') # True
print(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10) == 'abcde') # Want True, but False here

print(repr(BioSequence('abcde', 10)))
print('{!r}'.format(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10)))
```

**output**

```
SAME <class '__main__.BioSequence'> abcde
True
SAME <class '__main__.Exon'> abcde
True
OTHER <class '__main__.BioSequence'> abcde
True
OTHER <class '__main__.Exon'> abcde
True
OTHER <class '__main__.Exon'> abcde
True
CLASS BioSequence
[BioSequence abcde (s: 10, e: 15)]
CLASS Exon
[Exon abcde (s: 10, e: 15)]
```

---

Here's a rough implementation that makes `content` a member.

```
class BioSequence:
    def __init__(self, source, pos_s=0, pos_e=-1):
        if isinstance(source, BioSequence):
            self.content = source.content
            self.pos_s_chrom = source.pos_s_chrom
            self.pos_e_chrom = source.pos_e_chrom
        else:
            self.content = source
            if pos_e == -1:
                pos_e = pos_s + len(self.content)
            self.pos_s_chrom = pos_s
            self.pos_e_chrom = pos_e

    def __eq__(self, otherSequence):
        ''' Two sequnces are equal if pos_s_chrom, pos_e_chrom, and sequence itself is the same
           or if otherSequence is just a string, do a normal string comparison
        '''
        if isinstance(otherSequence, self.__class__):
            print('SAME', self.__class__, otherSequence)
            return (self.content == otherSequence.content 
                and self.pos_s_chrom == otherSequence.pos_s_chrom 
                and self.pos_e_chrom == otherSequence.pos_e_chrom)
        else: # just a string comparison
            print('OTHER', self.__class__, otherSequence)
            return self.content == otherSequence

    def __ne__(self, otherSequence):
        return not self.__eq__(otherSequence)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.content)

    def __repr__(self):
        className = self.__class__.__name__
        print('CLASS', className)
        return '[{} {} (s: {}, e: {})]'.format(className, self.content, self.pos_s_chrom, self.pos_e_chrom)


class Exon(BioSequence):
    pass

print(BioSequence('abcde', 10) == BioSequence('abcde', 10)) # True
print(Exon('abcde', 10) == Exon('abcde', 10)) # True
print(BioSequence('abcde', 10) == 'abcde') # True
print(Exon('abcde', 10) == 'abcde') # True
print(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10) == 'abcde') # Want True, but False here

print(repr(BioSequence('abcde', 10)))
print('{!r}'.format(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10)))
print(BioSequence('abcde', 10))
print('{}'.format(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10)))
```

**output**

```
SAME <class '__main__.BioSequence'> abcde
True
SAME <class '__main__.Exon'> abcde
True
OTHER <class '__main__.BioSequence'> abcde
True
OTHER <class '__main__.Exon'> abcde
True
OTHER <class '__main__.Exon'> abcde
True
CLASS BioSequence
[BioSequence abcde (s: 10, e: 15)]
CLASS Exon
[Exon abcde (s: 10, e: 15)]
abcde
abcde
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem with your code is that your `str` subclass implements `__str__`. Bad idea.

You know how calling `str(whatever)` delegates to `whatever.__str__`? That happens because `str.__new__` delegates to `whatever.__str__`. When you call `Exon(BioSequence(...), ...)`, your `__new__` delegates to `str.__new__`, *which delegates to `BioSequence.__str__`*. There's some [extra handling](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L14952) when creating a subclass instance, but the string content comes from `__str__`.

Rather than containing the characters of the BioSequence, your Exon contains the characters of the string returned by the BioSequence's `__str__` method. Those characters are not `abcde`, so naturally, the `__eq__` comparison fails.

Answer (score 2):

Printing `repr(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10))` is enough to explain the problem: it gives

```
"'[BioSequence abcde (s: 10, e: 15)]'"
```

As the `__str__` special method has been overriden, the conversion of a BioSequence to a plain string gives this detailed description. As a consequence, the `str` subobject of  `Exon(Exon(BioSequence('abcde', 10), 10)` is not `'abcde'` but `'[BioSequence abcde (s: 10, e: 15)]'`. This explains why the last comparison fails.

My advice is that you do not want to override `__str__` is a subclass of `str`. You have two possible paths here:

- override `__repr__` in your subclasses instead of `__str__`. It makes sense, because the `str` part of the subclasses shall be the simple string. When you want the detailed description, just use `repr`
- do not use inheritance but delegation. In this pattern, a `BioSequence` is not a `str` but only has a `str` member. This should give you a greater flexibility, but requires more boiler plate code.